# Laravel 5.7 Schema foreign key SQLSTATE[42000] migration

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am working on a school project where i need to use and erd to setup my database with laravel. I'm trying to get my migrations working with foreign keys.

How do I use foreign keys with laravel?

Here are my tables :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customer_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('customer_order_id');
        $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('customer_id')->on('customers');
        $table->float('totaal_bedrag');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('customer_id');
        $table->string('voornaam');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('adress');
        $table->tinyInteger('telefoon');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customer_order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('customer_order_product_id');
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('order_id')->on('customer_orders');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('product_id')->on('products');
        $table->float('totaal_bedrag');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}



    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('product_id');
        $table->float('prijs_product');
        $table->string('product_naam');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

When I remove the foreign keys, it all works fine.
For now i receive the following error message:

```
\\\\\\\\

        C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps>php artisan migrate:fresh -v
        Dropped all tables successfully.
        Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2019_01_13_151934_create_customer_orders_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'customer_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `customer_orders` add constraint `customer_orders_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`customer_id`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'customer_id' doesn't exist in table")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  3   Illuminate\Database\Connection::Illuminate\Database\{closure}("alter table `customer_orders` add constraint `customer_orders_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`customer_id`)", [])
      C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:657

  4   Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback("alter table `customer_orders` add constraint `customer_orders_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`customer_id`)", [], Object(Closure))
      C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:624

  5   Illuminate\Database\Connection::run("alter table `customer_orders` add constraint `customer_orders_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`customer_id`)", [], Object(Closure))
      C:\xampp\htdocs\newapps\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:459

  6   Illuminate\Database\Connection::statement("alter table `customer_orders` add constraint `customer_orders_customer_id_foreign` 
        foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`customer_id`
\\\\\\\\
```

Comment: Are the migrations being run in that specific order?

Comment: Yes they are (i think) was thinking about that also, do you know how i need to change it? the order must be 1. customers 2. customer_orders 3.customer_0rder_products 4.products

Comment: Migrations are run according to the time they were created. You would need to either rename the migration file's date or create new ones. Not sure that you could do otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a field before creating a foreign key. For example this should work:

```
Schema::create('customer_order_products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('customer_order_product_id');
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->float('totaal_bedrag');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('product_id')->on('products');
    $table->foreign('order_id')->references('order_id')->on('customer_orders');
});
```

Also make sure your migrations run in the right order. Migrations for `products` and `customer_orders` should be running before the above migration.

Comment: It works, but if i apply the same principal on my customers table its broken again:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `newapps`

Comment: Schema::create('customer_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('customer_order_id');
   $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
   $table->float('totaal_bedrag');
            $table->timestamps();
   
   $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('customer_id')->on('customers');
   
        });

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `newapps`.`#sql-31c_b6` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `customer_orders` add constraint `customer_orders_customer_id_foreign` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`customer_id`))

Comment: @T.DT migrations looks good. Try to delete all tables from database and run your migration again.

Comment: thanks i got everything working ( kind of ) but still get the 1005 error for some reason.  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `schoolexamen`.`#sql-19ec_f9` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `customer_order_products` add constraint `customer_order_products_order_id_foreign` foreign key (`order_id`) references `customer_orders` (`order_id`))

Comment: where "schoolexamen" is the name of my actual database, so dont know why it wants to create a table named after that.

Comment: Okay i got it now! i named the reference id wrong, it should be : customer_order_id and not order, id ! Thanks allot